# Highlighting changed folders in PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I really love highlighting of changes in editor and in project manager, but I would love it even more if there would be options to highlight folders. I can see single files changed, but in project that has very complicated structure is often difficult to find a file changed in a folder.

Is there anything that I can change in settings?

Comment: In addition to the answer by mgreshen -- you may also try "Changed Files" scope in Project View panel (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/project-tool-window.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to select the "Show directories with changed descendants" option in:

`File`->`Settings...`->`Version Control`->`Show directories with changed descendants`

[image]

Comment: this should be enabled by default

Comment: Thank you, thank you! Have been wanting this for a long while.

Answer (score 7):

In PhpStorm 2021.3 this option has name "Highlight directories that contain modified files in the Project tree" and you can find it in:

`File` -> `Settings` -> `Version Control` -> `Confirmation` -> `Changes`

[image: phpstorm Highlight directories option]

Comment: Thanks! What a weird setting placement.